# Mac Core Data UnCaught Exception

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I get this error:

```
2013-01-21 15:09:49.479 obtl[13136:403] An uncaught exception was raised
2013-01-21 15:09:49.484 obtl[13136:403] [<NSApplication 0x10012a600> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key managedObjectContext.
2013-01-21 15:09:49.493 obtl[13136:403] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c000f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff934f4d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c08b1b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ef65703 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 240
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ee9c38e _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 108
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ee9c315 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 392
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff938596ef -[NSApplication(NSScripting) valueForKey:] + 510
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8eebbda2 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 348
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff936572fa -[NSBinder _valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] + 654
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff93656fe4 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 171
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff93656c52 -[NSObjectParameterBinder _updateObject:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:] + 1181
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff93648f8f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 591
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff936422a1 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1079
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff936388bb loadNib + 322
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff93637db8 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff93637cd3 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff93637c16 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff938a8cd7 NSApplicationMain + 398
    18  obtl                                0x0000000100001b52 main + 34
    19  obtl                                0x0000000100001b24 start + 52
)
2013-01-21 15:09:49.503 obtl[13136:403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSApplication 0x10012a600> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key managedObjectContext.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c000f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff934f4d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c08b1b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ef65703 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 240
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ee9c38e _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 108
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ee9c315 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 392
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff938596ef -[NSApplication(NSScripting) valueForKey:] + 510
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8eebbda2 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 348
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff936572fa -[NSBinder _valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] + 654
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff93656fe4 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 171
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff93656c52 -[NSObjectParameterBinder _updateObject:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:] + 1181
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff93648f8f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 591
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff936422a1 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1079
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff936388bb loadNib + 322
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff93637db8 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff93637cd3 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff93637c16 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff938a8cd7 NSApplicationMain + 398
    18  obtl                                0x0000000100001b52 main + 34
    19  obtl                                0x0000000100001b24 start + 52
)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Related information:

Mac OSX App (trying to aim for users with Snow Leopard to be able to use it as well).
Everything is bound appropriately to `FileOwner.managedObjectContext` and the appropriate entity. I have triple checked all of my tables, buttons, etc to make sure that they are attached to the right bindings. 
I only have 1 window file. 
I am using Xcode 4.5.2 on Mac Lion (without using Auto Layout). I am lost as to how to fix this-and yes I have researched a lot of the similar questions and have tried some of the same solutions to no avail.

Comment: it seems the crash happens while loading a nib. could you show how you do that? `initWithWindowNibName`? `loadNibNamed`?

Comment: Its a non document based-I didn't bother or change anything with that. In the AppDelegate, it just shows @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window; (.h) and I can't seem to find something similar in the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

From the crash log, it appears that you are loading a nib and that the nib tries to access a `managedObjectContext` property defined in the nib's owner. It is not found, so the crash. This is probably due to a wrong nib owner.

I would suggest to review your nib file:

1. the file's owner should be of type: `NSApplication`;
2. the file's owner should have a `delegate` outlet bound to the app delegate;
3. the app delegate should declare the `managedObjectContext` property.

Comment: ok. I'll check that. How would I fix that if Xcode cannot find it (drag my arraycontrollers to the AppDelegate)?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong: the owner should be NSApplication... and the Owner should have a delegate binding to the app delegate...

Comment: Everything seems to be as you describe.